# How can I see only questions tagged with my preferred tags?

Tags: support, mobile-web, user-experience

The mobile site is quite spartan, and this ought to be helpful, but it seems it makes it harder to use.

So far I have determined:

- Tapping questions shows all questions. Those tagged with one of my favourite tags show up in yellow.
- There is no filter on questions to "just show yellow ones".
- Tapping tags shows all tags ranked by popularity.
- There is no tag filter for "just my favourites".

This means, my choices for seeing questions I'm likely to want to answer are:

- Scroll the list looking for yellow ones.
- Scroll the tags looking for one I know is a favourite and tap it.

Did I miss something more obvious/easier to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tap the search icon, type "intags:mine is:q", order by newest (or by active if you prefer). Then bookmark the URL.

Or skip the typing: [this is the URL to bookmark](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20is%3aq) ("newest" order).

Comment: You might also want to add `is:q` to that filter, so that you don't get answers also.

Comment: The page just endless loads for me